# Install template on joomla fails

Tags: php, joomla

When I try and upload / install a template zip file I just get a blank screen.

When I enable development level error messages I get a full page of

`Strict Standards: Non-static method JFTP::getInstance() should not be called statically in /libraries/joomla/filesystem/file.php on line 409`

with this

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /plugins/extension/joomla/joomla.php on line 220`

on the last line, and the template does not appear in the Manage tab.

I've had to enable the FTP layer as I have permission errors on my directories and that was one way of fixing them, I can see the file get uploaded to /tmp and an install__GUID folder is created but still nothing.

The install is Joomla! 2.5.1

Any suggestions appreciated.

Cheers,

JB

Answer (score 1):

Have you modified that file (`plugins/extension/joomla/joomla.php`)? Download a recent version and compare it with the file in the distribution.